# Unable to use Jupyter Notebook with the right Python version, and Jupyter kernel crashes automatically

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am frustrated with this now.

I have been using Jupyter for a long time, everything went well. But recently I did some changes (I don't even remember, But I am sure I was forced to do that due to some occations, I am the worst, I know), and now the when I use Jupyter, the kernel shows "Python 3":
[image]

But Jupyter actually uses python2.7 (because of the crash I can't even provide a screenshot). Even worse, every time I open the notebook, it automatically crashes after 10 seconds.
[image]
[image]

I wanted to remove it and reinstall it, I am not sure which `pip` did I use to install it, but whenever I execute both `pip2.7 uninstall jupyter` or `pip3.5 uninstall jupyter`, I get the same result: "***Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed***", so I can't even uninstall it.

And I am not using anaconda as well, I used to but later I found out jupyter couldn't import the packages install by anaconda at all so I uninstalled anaconda, so the jupyter I am using must be installed with `pip`.

Is there anyone who can help? I googled for a whole day trying to find solutions but couldn't. I am frustrated right now and really need to get back to my work.

Much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: So you don't know how you installed Jupyter originally? Try `which jupyter` if you are on a `*nix` environment. You should have just used `anaconda` from the beginning. Maybe just do that now.

Comment: Hi @ juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for the reply. I just checked, jupyter is located in `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`. So what I should do now?

Comment: should i just delete the whole directory and install again or what?

Comment: You should better always use a virtual environment, either from pip or anaconda. I personally like [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) the best. Otherwise, your Python versions are mixed now and confusing, and Jupyter somehow finds the Python3 first, which is why it's shown. As for " jupyter couldn't import the packages install by anaconda at all so I uninstalled anaconda", probably some configuration was wrong.

Comment: Thanks man. I deleted all the downloaded packages for all my python version and only using anaconda to download and manage them. so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore whatever Python version are installed, redownload [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html), then configure `PATH`, and rely on it exclusively for most Python related things. Inside a anaconda/miniconda virtual environment, you could still use pip. You may try

```
conda create -p venv -y python=2 scipy 

source activate venv/

jupyter notebook
```